# PHP Team development setup

Tags: php, ide

Im currently developing a website (PHP,MySQL,Javascript...) and i've been doing great so far. My current setup is a remote LAMP box and Eclipse with the RSE plugin. But now i have to figure out another setup for my team.
  So now im looking for a solution with version control and that would allow us to test the code on said box. Any ideas ?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[Netbeans](http://netbeans.org/) (x-platform) and [Coda](http://panic.com/coda/) (on Mac) pretty popular if you're looking for an IDE w/ integrated revision control via git, svn, etc.  Git and SVN are both extremely easy to setup, but I'd recommend git as the learning curve is slighter and IMO overall a better revision control system.

Alternatively, you can let everybody use whatever ide they want, force them to learn svn / git from the command line, and focus on standardizing your code approaches (ie frameworks and libraries) instead of your development environment.

I'd go with the latter approach, since diff people will be using diff operating systems and have diff preferences.

Comment: We've been using SVN for other projects, running on that same box. I was looking for a 'centralized solution' mainly for code testing. Trying no to use Wezly's solution :) although it seams like the best idea

Answer (score 0):

I recommend running local installs of mamp (or similar) on each user machine. Then use 'git' for version control with a remote host such as [codebasehq.com](http://www.codebasehq.com/) so that you can manage commits over your development team.